# presentation logic in controller ok

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is it ok to have some presentation logic in the controller and view model?

i'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>

    <% string isEnabled = "hidden"; %>

    <div style="visibility: <%= isEnabled %>">
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Next","Test") %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view and controller is most definetly for presentation logic.
Please note that it is best practice to not have too much logic in the view, and if you need it you can always add a view helper

Answer (score 2):

No in the controller and yes in the view model. That's exactly what view models are intended for.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case is better to do it in view.

But in some cases that you need to define more complex rules to the visibility of an area. It is better to make a combination using

```
<% Html.RenderAction("ActionName","ControllerName"); %>
```

Hope it helps!